# how can the computer distinguishes between keyboard USB and mouse USB?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Wondering how can the *PC* distinguish among multiple **USBs**. For example, when i plug my flash drive USB into my computer how can it know that it is a flash drive **USB** not a keyboard **USB** ?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. With that being said: When you plug in the device, the OS queries it for what it is, and the device tells it. It's just like when you walk into a restaurant and the waiter comes over. They ask you what you'd like to eat and you tell them. How else do you think it would be done?

Comment: thanks for response, i was just wondering how this is happening. you helped me and i got the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the USB standard there are **USB classes** a memory stick is *USB mass storage class*, keyboard, mouse, joystick are *USB HID class (Human Interface Device)*, cameras implement *USB PTP (picture transfer protocol)*, USB-to-serial (virtual COM ports,...) is *USB CDC ACM class* ,...

the following link lists all USB classes for that windows has drivers https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

when the USB device is plugged in there is a communication between the MCU on the USB device (firmware) and the PC (USB host) . in this communication the device says  which USB class it it and the host loads the fitting driver

you can sniff this communication using `wireshark` or see `dmesg` (on linux)

this communication is very low-level and not easily human-readable. there are tools like `wireshark` or `lsusb -v` for this

a USB device has to implement a special hierarchy of descriptors in which information of the internal structure of the USB device is contained. the hierachy is:

device descriptor -> configuration descriptor  -> interface descriptor  -> endpoint descriptor

EP0 is reserved for control transfers, else any transfer has to go to or come from an endpoint (OUT endpoint / IN endpoint)

see http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml

USB is a higly complex standard because it implements a wide functionality for a large number of different devices in one physical interface. i think the most complicated USB class standard is USB audio...